# how to make custom login with token in JSF with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jsf-2.2

I've requirement to login with username and password then upon valid credentials to send token on his mail and ask him to enter the token.

I'm setting Login.xhtml page as login page as follows, but the result I'm any form submission goes to authority filter not to the bean, I need it to capture the action in the managed bean first to validate inputs then send him token and validate his input.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login.xhtml", "/finance.xhtml", "/WEB-INF/errorpages/**",
                    "/javax.faces.resource/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.xhtml").failureUrl("/login.xhtml?authfailed=true").permitAll().and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml").logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout").and().csrf().disable();
```

Comment: I changed loginprocessingurl to fake url and kept login page, so it's redirecting to login page if not logged in and then I'm doing normal stuff to authenticate the user then use authmanger to auth, it's working fine but not optimal specially I'm making explicit redirect to home (not the page the user was accessing) ***Authentication auth = authenticationManager
     .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, token));
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
   Faces.redirect("/index.xhtml");

Comment: any ideas how to get the same behavior of spring to redirect back to the page the user hits before sending him to login

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work : requestedURI = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap()    .get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed loginprocessingurl to fake url and kept login page, so it's redirecting to login page if not logged in and then I'm doing normal stuff to authenticate the user then use authmanger to auth, it's working fine but not optimal specially I'm making explicit redirect to home (not the page the user was accessing) ***Authentication auth = authenticationManager .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, token)); SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth); Faces.redirect("/index.xhtml");